# Неоднозначная метка unity

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, синонимы-меток, удаление-метки, описание-метки

Метка [`unity`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/unity/info) может использоваться для обозначения как минимум:

1. Игрового движка [Unity3d](http://unity3d.com/) (для него уже есть [`unity3d`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/unity3d/info)).
2. Dependency injection контейнера [Unity Container](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity).
3. Рабочего стола [Unity](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/unity) в Ubuntu.

Сейчас `unity` используется практически полностью как синоним `unity3d`.

На [англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unity/info) - для обозначения Unity Container, и начинается с:

> **DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE** (use: [unity3d] instead) The Unity Application Block (Unity) is a
>   lightweight, extensible dependency injection container for .NET with
>   support for interception.

По-моему, стоит:

- либо убрать эту метку,
- либо сделать ее легальным синонимом `unty3d`,
- либо выбрать для нее другое значение и вставить соответствующее описание.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Всего 33 вопроса, можно перебрать вручную. Предлагаю такой сценарий:

1. Уточнить описание метки.
2. Перебираем вопросы, [где нет метки [unity3d]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity+-unity3d). Где вопрос не про unity3d, переставить метку:

   - [unity-container](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-container)
   - [unity-ubuntu](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity-ubuntu)
3. Потом оставшиеся вопросы синонимизировать стандартным путем.

Comment: unity-ubuntu уже переделал. за остальные не возьмусь, так как совсем «не в теме».

Comment: В оставшихся был [один вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423123/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%81-generic-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-unity-container) по unity-container. Заменил, если никто не откатит.

Comment: Плюс, обнаружился [вопрос по некой плате Unity Pro XL](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428021/these-ddt-instance-is-not-mapped-on-a-device-%D0%B2-unity-pro-xl-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8). Что с ним делать мне непонятно. Все остальные вопросы с меткой Unity - по Unity3d.

Comment: @Vladimir в Pro XL проголосовал за закрытие.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, это уже хорошо)

Comment: Господа, почему алиас? Почему не заменить правками на Unity3D?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Здесь, видимо, тоже [meta-tag:статус-завершено]?